# Vertical line is not visible in Outlook

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a progress update e-mail. I have two main percentage calculations:

1. Actual Percentage: What is the actual number of completed items, used to fill the progress bar.
2. Target Percentage: What was the target number of completed items for this time, used to put a vertical line on the progress bar.

I create the html file dynamically from a Scala back-end task. I am copying created html string to a test.html file, see the code:

Style section:

```
.vl {
  border-left: 3px solid black;
  height: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

Body section:

```
<table style="border:0;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="250">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:0.0%; background-color:red; float:left; height:15px;"></td>
            <td style="width:100.0%; background-color:#cccccc; float:left; height:15px;"><div class="vl" style = "left: 98.75777%"></div></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, when I open the test.html file on a browser (chrome, explorer, edge all the same) I can see my progress bar (sort of) seems correct:

[image]

But when I send the e-mail, outlook doesn't show "target percentage":

[image]

I've faced the same issue for example with progress tag, it was perfect in browser but not working in the mail so I used td's with percentages. But since this vertical line is completely defined css style by me, I couldn't find a work-around for this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found which features are not supported on Outlook on this [website](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). For my particular example it was position tags.

I've removed position tags and converted whole structure to a table so I could find a work around for position tags.